# Echo text based on level_id for SocialEngine 4.x/Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, socialengine

I must confess, I am quite new to working with php inside a javascript block. As a temporary fix until I can write something more dynamic, I need to pass text based on the user level, if they are not logged in, I am using the else to identify as such. I have a variable called member_level inside a javascript block, I have the following code below inside double quotes but it doesn't like the formatting. I just cannot see what is wrong. I am sorry if this question is worded wrong, just on my last candle and can't see what I am doing wrong

```
    var chat_role = "<?php if($this->viewer()->level_id == '1'){
                echo Super Admin;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '3'){
                echo Moderator;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '4'){
                echo Free;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '5'){
                echo Public;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '9'){
                echo Premium;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '13'){
                echo Corporate;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '15'){
                echo Lifetime;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '16'){
                echo Standard Admin;
  } else if($this->viewer()->level_id == '17'){
                echo New Member;
  } else {
                echo Non Logged In;
  }
endif ?>
";
```

What is it I am missing? I am truly not asking someone to write the code, just give me an idea of where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
var chat_role = "<?php echo (isset($this->viewer()->level_id) && $this->viewer()->level_id > 0 ? Engine_Api::_()->getItem('authorization_level', $this->viewer()->level_id)->getTitle(): 'Non Logged In'); ?>";
```

Comment: I used the same code before. What happens is non-logged in users get a zend error. and the page doesn't load.

Comment: Try the updated one, have applied isset to check first

Comment: I have completed the testing and why I didn't consider isset is beyond me - your code works - I am also going to post an alternative I came up with as well later today. Yours however is the cleaner and more effective approach! - THANKS!